# Neo4j webadmin shows more nodes than query returns

Tags: neo4j

I deleted some useless nodes from my database (about 600K) I used query below

```
match (m:MOVIE)
with m
limit 100000
where (m)--()
delete m
```

In webadmin count of nodes was decreasing.

After about 5 times I executed it it deleted I don't know maybe 200-300K nodes I changed limit to `200000` and then database suddenly disconnected for some reason. I closed neo4j client cause it wasn't responding and started it again and then go back to browser. I looked to webadmin and there was old numbers. I again start to executing query above until it returned that no nodes were deleted.

Then I checked webadmin and there was about 900K nodes.

I executed query below

```
match (n)
return count(n)
```

and it returned only 500K nodes which seems to be right. But why in webadmin is different number? I know that after delete some values remain but when I was deleting nodes in webadmin counts decreased not remain same.

And what is also strange, my database used 1850MB of disk space and after delete it is using 1975MB.

Why is this happening? Is something wrong or I did something wrong?

Comment: Have you restarted?  Sometimes that gives Neo4j a chance to clean up after a big set of deletes.  Also, what version of Neo4j are you using?

Comment: Yes I restarted neo4j client and also computer but values are still same. And i´m using version 2.2.0-RC01

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The old Neo4j webadmin chart shows actually the "highest-id" not the number of nodes. So just ignore that chart.

```
match (n)
return count(*)
```

is the correct count.

Comment: Yes I read some questions here about that. And it is not very important but it interest me. As I said, count of nodes in webadmin decreased when I executed query for deleting nodes, but after disconnect there were old values. Than again I deleted rest of useless nodes and count of nodes decreased e.g. I had 1200K nodes, deleted 200K, value decreased to 1000K then disconnected. I started client again and there was 1200K again. Deleted 300K and value is now 900K but should be 700K. And I'm using version 2.2.0-RC01 so not old. Maybe it is some bug and than this is information for developers.